# iOS Push notification not received in development mode

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I used push notification in one of my apps, in this, I have not received notification in development mode. When I run my app, the device token generated is of 64 bit. I test these tokens in Pushtry.com but only getting the message of push notification sent successfully but not getting on the device.

Comment: Is Development SSL certificate valid one ??

Comment: @Anuraj - Yes its valid certificate.

Comment: I would recommend to test for certificate's validity once at your end. you can save the file from [simplepush.php](https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush) and run it with php command as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush)